# Pundit authorization when 2 user models + admin role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, pundit

I'm new to Rails and exercising. I have two user models, Student and Prof. I added an admin role to the Student model with enum.

I want to allow a Prof's profile to be edited by the owner of the profile or an admin.

Here is my code in profile_policy.rb:

```
def update?
 is_owner? || user.admin? if user
end
[...]
def is_owner?
 record.prof == user
end
```

and in my show view, I want to show the link "edit" only based on the Pundit authorization:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_prof_profile_path(@prof.id, @profile.id) if policy(@profile).edit? %>
```

In my application controller I have a custom current_user method that includes both current_student and current_prof.

The problem is that `user.admin?` calls the admin method on the Prof model, which doesn't have such method, so I get the error `undefined method admin?` when a Prof who isn't the owner wants to visit a profile.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that eventually worked for me, using `try()`

In my policy file, I add this custom method checking if the user has or not a `role` defined as `"admin`. This method will return `true` or `false`, as expected by Pundit.

```
def is_admin?
  user.try(:role) == "admin"
end
```